# PHP displaying JPG image from PNG source on server?

Tags: php, png, converters, jpeg

Is it possible to have png images on my server but have a php script that converts them to jpg (and compresses them) and caches them when viewed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script for convert PNG image into JPEG image.

```
$input_file = "test.png";
$output_file = "test.jpg";

$input = imagecreatefrompng($input_file);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($input_file);
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($output, $input, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($output, $output_file);
```

You can go through this [@Alexandre Jasmin Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569970/gd-converting-a-png-image-to-jpeg-and-making-the-alpha-by-default-white-and-not/2570015#2570015).

Comment: It appears this doesn't cache the image, ie. they are regenerated each time the page is viewed (would this be a problem for speed?), what would I have to add to this script to cache? So it only generates a new jpg if the png has changed from the last time a jpg was generated.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, you can google it using phrase "**png convert to jpg php**"

[Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression)